# Query in react native about sliding up panel

Tags: react-native

In React Native iOS, I would like to slide in and out of a like in the following picture.

So I installed this  https://github.com/octopitus/rn-sliding-up-panel for ease.

[image: This is whole Code]

but this error is showing =>

[image: Error]

i cant understand whats wrong, I am new to react native. Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access variable called _panel from this object because you are inside a function itself. besides you are using function based react, in order to create a reference check useRef() hook or switch to class based component and then you can use this._panel;

smthg like this:

```
function AccessingElement() {
  const elementRef = useRef();


  const onPress = () => {
    // e.g
    elementRef.current.show();
  } 
  return (
    <View ref={elementRef}>
      ...child views
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: should  i create a different js file for this?

Comment: nope you can do it in the same file, inside the App function declare the const variable using useRef; then on the jsx assign that ref to the specific tag and you can use it like that: elementRef.current

Comment: or what you can do, instead of declaring the app function you can switch to a component Idk if you want to go hooks or class based; but switching to component will solve the issue; you app function would be converted to export default class App extends React.Component {....}

Comment: ohh ok so what changes should i do in the <Button> to <SlidingUpPanel> code to add it in your "...child views".

Comment: nothing, the one above was just an example with the hooks; just rename the reference instead of using this._panel.show() use it as elementRef.current.show()

Comment: ohh ok i will see if first code you gave is working else i am switching to component .

Comment: ok got it i coverted the function to class but there is a issue i dont want that panel in first page...i want it from second slide.

Comment: refer to the documentation, https://octopitus.github.io/rn-sliding-up-panel/ , you should create an animated value and then set it to the corresponding panel that you want to show first, If I understand correctly